# Android MP4 stream - Video cannot be played

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, mp4

So i am streaming a video from a URL into the androids video view and its MP4.

Here's my code:

```
String LINK = "String LINK = "http://www.fieldandrurallife.tv/videos/Benltey%20Mulsanne.mp4";
setContentView(R.layout.video);
VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();";
```

I get the dialog box saying "This Video cannot be played" BUT if i change the link url to "http://www.boisestatefootball.com/sites/default/files/videos/original/01%20-%20coach%20pete%20bio_4.mp4" Then it works! Does anyone know why? and how can i fix it?

Many Thanks

Comment: if video is not present to that url then such type of dialog appears.

Comment: if u are trying to fetch the video which is not present to that perticular url, then video is not played and msg that "This Video cannot be played" is appear on the screen.

Comment: but the video is here, http://www.fieldandrurallife.tv/videos/Benltey%20Mulsanne.mp4 - this link works the same in a browser

Comment: just because they both end in .mp4 doesn't mean those videos have the same format

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it played the video for me

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoViewa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

```
            VideoView videoView;

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewa);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    //URI either from net
    Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.fieldandrurallife.tv/videos/Benltey%20Mulsanne.mp4");
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: still i got same issue ,please help me solve out this :(